# How to include files inside a function and still grant the functions of included file global scope in php

Tags: php, include, scope

i was bitten by some ABSTRACTION & ORGANISATION bug and i decided that i would include files in my php application by using a class called Loader which looks like this

```
class Loader
{
    public $loadedFiles=array();

    public function isLoaded($fileName)
    {
        if(in_array($fileName,$this->loadedFiles))
        return true;
        else 
        return false;
    }

    public function load()
    {
        $fileList=func_get_args();
        foreach ($fileList as $file)
        {
            if(!$this->isLoaded($file))
            {
                $flag=include(ROOT_DIR_PATH.'includes'.DS.$file);
                if($flag)
                {
                    $this->loadedFiles[]=$file;

                }
                else
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now i can include files in my app using something like this

```
$loader=new Loader();
$loader->load('db.class.php','utility.php','objects.php');
```

but the problem is that now all the functions of the files included by the above method are granted the scope of the above method `load`. now i cant use any functions of the included files   . Whenever i use any function of the above included files i get a warning saying `undefined function`. Is there some way i can grant global scope to the functions of the included files.

Comment: is the path $flag=include(ROOT_DIR_PATH.'includes'.DS.$file); correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is somewhere else. I have tried to simulate what you were trying to do and it worked for me. 
**include1.php**

```
 <?php
 function tester()
     echo "This is tester\n";
 }
```

**include2.php**

```
<?php

class Loader {
    public function load() {
        $var = include('include1.php');
    }
}

$loader = new Loader();
$loader->load();
tester();
```

And the result was this: ***This is tester***

There wasn't any scoping issue. As @JackTurky mentioned, check the path.